# Adding UIButton top bar of a navigation controller that pushes to another viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIButton` that pushes to another view controller using the following code. How do I go about putting this `UIButton` to the top bar of a navigation controller.

```
-(IBAction) nextButtonPressed {     
    TipsViewController *objYourViewController = [[TipsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TipsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objYourViewController animated:YES];
    [TipsViewController release];
}
```

I was thinking of adding something like: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` somewhere, but can't figure out the syntax.

Here's something else I tried with the following code: I can get a "Next" button in the top bar of the Navigation Controller. How would I get it to push to another view controller?

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self pushViewController:anotherButton animated:YES];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
[anotherButton release];
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init your UIBarButtonItem, do you see a parameter called action: ? Mention a selector there:

```
UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Next:)];
```

The above item should be your rightBarButton as you want it to be.

And this would be your selector:

```
-(void)Next:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItem  addButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"+" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(method)];